# PHP mailer works on Local Machine but not on AWS LightSail server

Tags: php, phpmailer, bitnami

My Problem is that PHP mailer works on my local machine, but does not work when I deploy the script to my AWS Lightsail server.

I have tried setting the proper file (644) and folder(755) permissions, still nothing works.

I have the function deployed on other servers, without any issue

*The error message*

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in

*How I include the mail function*
`require('transit/mail.php');`

*The content of my mail function.*

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

function send_mail($sender, $senderName, $recipient, $subject, $bodyText, $bodyHtml){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. These are the steps I followed.

1. Connect to the server via ssh terminal
2. Navigate to the php mailer folder

   3. Run `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`

This was the message received.

> Using version ^6.1 for phpmailer/phpmailer
>   ./composer.json has been created
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Writing lock file
>   Generating autoload files

It worked afterwards.

Comment: If you find that using `composer require` solves your issue, then your whole development setup was broken to start with. It's reasonable to run `composer install` when deploying on your server, but you really shouldn't be running `composer require` on there. Work on your scripts locally, including setting up dependencies, and then upload your scripts plus your composer `json` and `lock` files, and then run `composer install`. This is what the PHPMailer and composer docs (and my answer) suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This means you either have not run `composer install` on your server, or you didn’t run it locally and upload its vendor folder with your other scripts.

Comment: I have solved the issue. These are the steps I followed.

Connect to the server via ssh terminal
Navigate to the php mailer folder
Run composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
This was the message received.

Using version ^6.1 for phpmailer/phpmailer ./composer.json has been created Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Nothing to install or update Writing lock file Generating autoload files
It worked afterwards